# Pass Data to next ViewController Using UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITableView that allows multiple selections. I'd like to pass the selections to the next "Q2ViewController" when user clicks the rightBarButtonItem "Next".
Note: I'm not using Storyboard. After searching through, I haven't found a solution without using storybaord.

```
var options = ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner", "dessert"]
    var selected = -1

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Q1View"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .Done, target: self, action: "didTapNext:")
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        var nib = UINib(nibName: "OptionCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView?.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "OptionCellIdentifier")
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.options.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OptionCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as OptionCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.options[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere in your code you must create the "next" view controller. Either in your App Delegate or directly in the view controller shown above.

If you create the view controller outside the above one you will have to pass the above controller a reference to the destination view controller.

If you create the view controller inside the above one save a reference to it in an instance variable.
Or create a method that creates the VC on pressing the "Next" button and pushes the VC to the navigation controller.

You can use `UITableView`'s `indexPathsForSelectedRows()` or similar to get the selection and then call a method/set a instance variable on the destination view controller.

But seriously, why don't you use storyboards?

Comment: I already have the next viewcontroller created with a separate swift and xib file. Is it possible for me to incorporate storyboards into my project at this point?